# UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString not working in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

I am new to UIWebView and especially stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method.
In my layoutSubviews, I am calling my webview to get the frame size.

```
 [self.body setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,10.0f,320.0f,[[_body stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] floatValue])];
```

It tries to find the height but leaves lots of space in the view meaning it does not give the correct height with text string.
Now the above code works perfectly on iOS 4 and it does not work on iOS 5.

Is there any other way I can change the following to get it work on iOS 5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, evaluate your javascript on its own:

```
NSString* result = [_body stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"];
NSLog(@"My JS is returning %@",result);
```

Make sure this is providing the correct value.  I believe the JS engine was modified from 4.0 to 5.0 so it may be handling it differently.

Comment: yeah it is providing the correct value. But what does the JS engine modified means from 4.0 to 5.0 ? There are actually two strings called on two different subviews.

Comment: It means that the value provided by `document.body.offsetHeight` may have changed.  If the NSLog() is showing the correct value, then your `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString` method **is** working and your problem relies in `self.body`'s positioning.

Comment: I believe the body is correctly positioned because it works correctly in iOS 4, it does not work in iOS 5.

Comment: Yeah, but just repeating over and over "It works in iOS 4 and not in iOS 5" isn't going to help us fix it.  Is `body` your webview?  Are you *certain* the *exact* same code and situation gives different results on iOS 4 and 5?

Comment: Yes, body is my webview and its the same exact code which gives different results in iOS 4 and iOS 5.